# Can Single Sign On (SAML) be used to integrate SAP's ERP with Google for Work?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, google-apps, sap-erp

My company is already using Google for Work and we're currently in the final stages of implementing SAP instead of Oracle. We want users to be able to login with their Google credentials.

The implementation team is not experienced in SSO, so I'm asking if it's possible to use SAML 2.0 to let users login to SAP using their Google credentials. If so, where can we start?

Answer (score 0):

plenty of docu out there. SAP support SAML2 and OAUTH. 
Just one of example of many  http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Using+OAuth+2.0+from+a+Web+Application+with+SAML+Bearer+Assertion+Flow